# Displaying a Dialog with a full screen image only takes up 80% of the screen

Tags: android, dialog, viewgroup, layoutparams

I want to display an image full-screen then dismiss when the user presses it.

I'm using a Dialog and it takes up about 80% of the screen. There's a white border around my image (it's not there in my file system).

How do I make this Dialog go completely full screen?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean viewedInstructions = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("instructions_viewed", false);
        if (!viewedInstructions) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("instructions_viewed", true);
            editor.commit();

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            d.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.instructions_dialog);
            d.findViewById(R.id.tutorial).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });

            d.show();
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tutorial"
        android:src="@drawable/dashboard_instructions"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try using @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar for your Dialog style?

Comment: How do I change theme of a Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this line

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
```

with

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: I'm marking that as accept, that's pretty good doesn't max out the screen still has a white border but better than what I had.

Comment: you can still change the background color of your dialog, but you have to inflate a layout with a background tag like this: android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 final Dialog d = new Dialog(this,R.style.MyDialogStyle);
```

And define this style in your styles.xml:

```
 <!-- Animation for dialog box -->
    <style name="MyDialogStyle"       parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </style>
```

You can also define it in the Manifest, setting it for the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.YourActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
 </activity>
```